# Increment variable on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i´m working on an interactive Infographic. Basically there are is a number of circles flying around. I try to change the amount of circles by clicking on a button, therefor I want to increase the **variable d** by 1 on click, to get an other element from the array. But it doesnt´t work. Any ideas?

```
var leuko = ["167", "143", "134", "96"]; //array


var d = 0; //variable

$("#day").click(function() {

d += 1;
```

_

```
for (var i = 0; i < leuko[d]; i++) {

var x = 20 + (Math.random() * (canvasWidth - 40));
var y = 20 + (Math.random() * (canvasHeight - 40));

var radius = 5;
var vX = Math.random() * 0.2;
var vY = Math.random() * 0.2;
```

I hope you can understand my problem, as my english isn´t the best.

Here is a jsfiddle-link. Layout looks a little bit messed up..

http://jsfiddle.net/JDU6H/

Thanks!

Comment: your script is incrementing `d`, but the problem is, that this variable is used only once on document ready..

Comment: Yes, `d` is incrementing fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/JDU6H/1/

Comment: If you want to totally rewrite your code, I could help you in StackOverflow chat here. My first language is German ;)

Comment: Sounds good to me ;) Which Channel?

Comment: @FelixSchneider Click here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19373/increment-variable-on-click-jquery

Comment: Looks like i cant respond untill I have 20 reputation. Gmail-Chat maybe?

Comment: @FelixSchneider Sorry, I think IRC is somewhat easier to setup. Join `#incrementVars`: http://webchat.quakenet.org/

Comment: just need to wrap all your code other than the click into one big function and call that function both on page load and inside the click handler

Answer (score 1):

**Without rewriting many parts of your code**, you can simply change your click function:

```
$("#day").click(function() {
    d += 1;

    var x = 20 + (Math.random() * (canvasWidth - 40));
    var y = 20 + (Math.random() * (canvasHeight - 40));

    var radius = 5;
    var vX = Math.random() * 0.2;
    var vY = Math.random() * 0.2;

    zellen.push(new Zelle(x, y, radius, vX, vY));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JDU6H/2/

Nevertheless I'd recommend you creating a class for all cells and adding an *add()* function.

Comment: This works fine. The only problem is, that I dont want to add just one more circel, but change the elemet from the array. For example I want to draw leuko[0] (167 circles) and then change the element to leuko[1] (143 circles) and so on...